# Autosys : Achieve dependency for two jobs in a BOX

Tags: autosys

**Scenario :** Two jobs are in a BOX_JOB - `JOB_1 and JOB_2`  , JOB_2  is dependent on `JOB_1 Success` and should `fail whenever JOB_1 fails`.

**Observation:** Once the BOX_JOB gets activated JOB_1 and JOB_2 both gets activated , but JOB_2 continues to be activated even when JOB_1 has completed as failure

**JOB_2 JIL**

```
job_type: cmd

....

condition: s(JOB_1)
box_name: BOX_JOB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the box_terminator attribute.  Set **box_terminator: 1** (or y) in the JIL for JOB_1 and it will terminate BOX_JOB if JOB_1 fails and JOB_2 should go to INACTIVE.

Check out page 204 (among others) of the [Autosys Reference Guide (pdf)](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Workload%20Automation%20AE%20Release%2011%203%206%20-%20Public%20Access-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/PDF/WA_AE_User_ENU.pdf) for more.